# How to connect real device to android studio?

Tags: android

Android Studio doesn't connect my  real device but , I am completed to all below the options ? Please solution me provide ....where is my missing...

1. Enable Debugging on the Device
2. Install USB Drivers
3. Connect the Device to the Computer

[image]

Comment: Pitfall: If you have a cable that for whatever reason doesn't support data transfer (yes, those exist. Cables that can't transfer any data, just charging use. i got one, can't believe those actually exist) that could be why. Make sure the cable works

Comment: downad and install adb drivers http://adbdriver.com/

Comment: when connecting your phone, is it shows under your devices and drives (usually "This PC" in windows 10)

Comment: Hello please check the answer..i think will work. if not work please tell me..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please download & install pdanet..this will definitely work..you can download from the link http://pdanet.co/a/.

Answer (score 0):

if you go to developer option check if "Usb Debuging" is Enabled